# JQuery Validator Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I have managed to implement the validator on a form, and is working fine for all my needs apart from a crucial last one.

Does anyone know how I would go about (or whether it's even possible) to extend or create a validation message that is purely a warning but still allows the form to be submitted (i.e. the field is still valid).

To illustrate this; I have an field that is required, number, and within a range (0 - 99999), but I want to show a warning (as per the error messages) if say type in over 5000 saying that this value is high for their circumstances, consider changing it.

Hope that makes sense!

---

EDIT:
Sorry should have mentioned that I would like the message to appear as all the other validation error messages at the side of the element when they leave focus. I didn't know whether it was possible to still have a rule that fires after all the others are valid but at the same time mark the field as valid or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the submitHandler from the [validate options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    if (value > BIG_VALUE) {
        if (confirm("...")) {
           form.submit();
        }
    }
    else {
      form.submit();
    }
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry should have mentioned that I would like the message to appear as all the other validation error messages at the side of the element when they leave focus. I didn't know whether it was possible to still have a rule that fires after all the others are valid but at the same time mark the field as valid or something?